# Why does File related stuff not Work? (Java)

Tags: java, file, java-io

Im currently writing a program which involves creating a Folder and a File within this Folder.
The first version worked, after that i decided to create a new project to give the code a clear form.
Now, suddenly the class creating the Files wont work anymore. I switched devices with the second project.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;

public class File {
    File folder1 = new File("Data");
    File file1 = new File("Data/MonData.txt"); 

    //For both "Data" and "Data/MonData.txt it says 
    //"Expected 0 arguments but found 1"

    public void DataText() {
        if(folder1.exists()) {         //exists = cant
        }                              //resolve method
        else {
            folder1.mkdirs();          //mkdirs = cant
        }                              //resolve method
        if(file1.exists()) {           //exists = cant
        }                              //resolve method
        else {
            try {
                file1.createNewFile(); //createNewFile = cant 
            }                          //resolve method
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should name your class in a different way. Naming your class `File` let java use it instead of java.io.File, so the method `exists` (and so the others) is not found because not in your class.

Comment: Thanks alot there. Im still new to Java, only learning c in school and the company im in wont help me either. (though thats their task in an apprenticeship..) Im very thankful i get some help here at least, even though it was a stupid mistake by me..

Comment: @AMIIGAF This is a good reason not to use `*` imports, by the way; conflicts are harder to notice.

Answer (score 0):

Your class name & importing class has same name `File`, So compiler check for your `File` class not `java.io.File` one which he should.

> In case two class had same name, use `java.io.File` & `your.File` instead of `File` only

Answer (score 0):

Both the classes of yours have the same name. Try naming the class `File` to `java.io.File` .
It should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use fully qualified name

```
java.io.File folder1 = new java.io.File("Data");
java.io.File file1 = new java.io.File("Data/MonData.txt");
```